# Vue with webkit - Unexpected token punc «(», expected punc «:»

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, uglifyjs

I have an error when trying to uglify a vuejs project

```
 Unexpected token punc «(», expected punc «:»
```

It is actually when trying to export a component nav.vue

```
export default {
  props: ['pageName'],
  data () {
    return {
      activeNav:0
    }
  },
```

It does not seem to like the data() syntax. Has anyone solved this?

Answer (score 2):

I simply did not have a .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]

}
```

Comment: Thanks!

Such a silly mistake, I had forgot to copy the file while transferring the project to another destination, this was exactly the issue although the contents of the file are different from yours.
```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", { "modules": false }],
    "stage-3"
  ]
}
```